# What does it mean 'Legacy octal literals are not allowed in strict mode in react js'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing an error that shows legacy octal literals are not allowed while working on context API in react. For reference, I am attaching a code snippet below.

`const [mission, setMission] = useState({ name: "go to russia", agent: 007, accept: "Not accepted", })`

Comment: Put quotes around 007…

Answer (score 2):

A number starting with a `0` is treated as an octal instead of a decimal.

```js
const value = 010;
console.log(value);
```

This can be confusing so it has been forbidden in your circumstance.

`007` is the same as `7` anyway. If the leading-zero formatting is important then use a string instead (either there where you have `007` or you can use `7` there and [format the number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros) on output).

```js
const data = { agent: "007" };
console.log(data.agent);
```

```js
const format = {
  minimumIntegerDigits: 3,
  minimumFractionDigits: 0,
  useGrouping: false
};
const data = {
  agent: 7
};
console.log(data.agent.toLocaleString('en', format));
```

Which you use will depend on if you ever need to treat `agent` as a number or not.